# Background image showing in safe area on the Splash Screen for iPhone X

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

This is how the Splash Screen for iPhone X looks like:

[image]

After UI renders, the problem disappire:

[image]

The problem starts after I use `UseSafeArea="true"` at some other pages.

```
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
```

But I didn't touched the MainPage.

I explicitly set `ios:Page.UseSafeArea="false"` but it didn't help.

Any idea how to fix the Splash Screen?

Googling didn't helped.

Comment: Hoy can try yo edit LaunchScreen xib on XCode Android full they entire screen

Comment: Do you want to use the safe area or not?

Comment: I don't want to use safe area at Splash Screen.

Answer (score -2):

Your launch screen whether has UseSafeArea="true".

Comment: I  explicitly set ios:Page.UseSafeArea="false"